# How to Exit If Statement and Run Another IF Statement?

Tags: php

```
$var1="exit";
$var2="run";
$var3="go";

if($var1 != '' && $var2 != '' && $var3 != '' ){

//first condtion
if($var1 == 'clear'){
  echo 'clear';
}
else {
  exit();
}

//2nd condtion
if($var2 == 'run'){
  echo 'run';
}

//3rd condtion
if($var3 == 'go'){
  echo 'go';
}

}
```

**I try to Exit() First If Condition, continue to next IF Condition, But Cannot Continue next IF condition totally Exit Overall Please Fix My Problem Thankyou **

Comment: don't put an else if there's nothing to do in else - and don't "make up syntax" ... exit()? why exit()?

Comment: what is your primary goal ?

Comment: Why `javascript` tag? Describe more what you want.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use else condition if you want to run second if statement

```
if($var1 != '' && $var2 != '' && $var3 != '' ){

//first condtion
if($var1 == 'clear'){
    echo 'clear';
}

//2nd condtion
if($var2 == 'run'){
    echo 'run';
}

//3rd condtion
if($var3 == 'go'){
    echo 'go';
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What About the idea of this one.

```
<?php

$var1="exit";
$var2="run";
$var3="go";

if($var1 != '' && $var2 != '' && $var3 != '' )
{   
    if($var2 == 'run'){
      echo 'run';
    }

    elseif($var3 == 'go'){
      echo 'go';
    }
    elseif($var1 == 'clear'){
      echo 'clear';
    }
    else {
      exit();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

just use only if.. use `return`

```
$var1="exit";
$var2="run";
$var3="go";

if($var1 != '' && $var2 != '' && $var3 != '' ){

//first condtion
   if($var1 == 'clear'){
      echo 'clear';
   }else {
      return;
   }

//2nd condtion
   if($var2 == 'run'){
     echo 'run';
   }else {
      return;
   }

//3rd condtion
   if($var3 == 'go'){
      echo 'go';
   }else {
      return;
   }

}
```